# Shadow перекрывают тескт

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер. Тени при наведении перекрывают текст в нижних блоках. z-index не помогает. Как исправить?
http://londonjack.ru/x/site11/index

Comment: Проблема была в overflow: hidden;